# Jquery dynamic list item select first filtered search item

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

My question, when user search text on input field how do I select first filtered matching list item? and if user click enters it automatically click first selected item. I will be very thankful for your help. Thanks in advance.

```
//pug file which displays dynamic list items. Each list item has href tag url link.  

 .row
   .col-md-8.offset-md-2.pad
    .form(class="form-row justify-content-center deparrSearchForm")    
      .form-group.col-md-8
        input(type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="fromStation" name="fromStation" placeholder="Type train station name & press enter")
    for prop in stationName
      ul(class="list-group text-center" id="mylist")
          a(href="/train/search-deparrtrain-submit/"+prop.stationShortCode+'/'+prop.stationName) 
           li(class="list-group-item") #{prop.stationName}

// Jquery which filter my input search text and display list items

$("#fromStation").on("keyup", function() {
var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();  

 $("#mylist li").filter(function(){
    var text= $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if(text.indexOf(searchText) >= 0){
      $(this).show();  
    }
    else{
      $(this).hide();
    }    
 });
});
```

Comment: For filter part you can use `first()`   https://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: I tried that, it select all list item not only the first filtered one.

Comment: Can you make codepen, jsbin or something like that with your full code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `index` in filter function like:

```
 $("#mylist li").filter(function(index){
    var text= $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if(text.indexOf(searchText) >= 0){
      $(this).show();    
    }
    else{
      $(this).hide();
    }    
 });
```

Then find that element by `eq` something like `$( this ).eq( index )` do anything you wan.

or use `$("#mylist").eq(index)` in filter function.

Comment: @ShekharAryal, Good to hear that, if you think it helped you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

For input field keypress function I pass the event, dynamic list filter function I pass the index.

In the filter function, I assign the index value of filtered list item to the temporary array. I get all the filtered list item position. Now I can do whatever I want to do. For my case, if user press enter key, I will display the first filtered list items.

Jquery Code:

```
$("#fromStation").on("keypress",function(e) {
var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
var temparr=[];
$("#mylist li").filter(function(index){
    var text= $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if(text.indexOf(searchText) >= 0){
      $(this).show().first();
      temparr.push(index);
    }
    else{
      $(this).hide();
    }
});
if(e.which == 13){
  $("#mylist li").eq(temparr[0]).click();
  console.log(temparr);
  return false;
 }
```

});